# Using Ksign and Comodo certificate unable to digitally sign Java installer built using JPackage with Java 21, okay with Java 20

Tags: java, certificate, code-signing, jpackage

My Java application uses Oracles **JPackage** to build an installation, I then use **ksigncmd** to digitally sign the installer using a certificate provided by comodo

e.g.

```
c:\Code\jthink\SongKong>"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-20.0.2.9-hotspot\bin\jpackage" --add-launcher SongKongDebug=songkongdebug.properties --add-launcher SongKongRemote=songkongremote.properties @jpackage.txt

c:\Code\jthink\SongKong>attrib -r SongKong-10.0.exe

c:\Code\jthink\SongKong>C:\Apps\Code\kSign\ksigncmd /d "SongKong Installer" /du "http://jthink.net/songkong" /f c:\code\signing\comodo.pfx /p password SongKong-10.0.exe
```

Been working for many years.

To resolve an issue with JPackage I would like to use the Java 21 version of JPackage but when I do that signing now fails with *An unknown error has occured. Please contact your vendor for assistance*

e.g.

```
c:\Code\jthink\SongKong>"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin\jpackage" --add-launcher SongKongDebug=songkongdebug.properties --add-launcher SongKongRemote=songkongremote.properties @jpackage.txt

c:\Code\jthink\SongKong>attrib -r SongKong-10.0.exe

c:\Code\jthink\SongKong>C:\Apps\Code\kSign\ksigncmd /d "SongKong Installer" /du "http://jthink.net/songkong" /f c:\code\signing\comodo.pfx /p password SongKong-10.0.exe
An unknown error has occured. Please contact your vendor for assistance
```

What could be the change in the Java 21 build that prevents **ksigncmd** working ?

Comment: How to reproduce this on the local? I'm using mac. I have already downloaded the SongKong app.

Comment: `kSignCMD` is now [obsolete](https://support.ksoftware.net/support/solutions/articles/17169-how-do-i-automate-code-signing-with-innosetup-and-ksign-). You should not use it anymore.

Comment: @AnishB. hi its a windows only issue

Comment: @Olivier thx will look into new tool, still interested in how new version of JPackage could break existing tool though

Comment: I guess only K Software could give you an explanation.

Comment: @Oliver i thought a Java expert might know of some key difference with jpackage 21

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `ksigncmd` you are not using the most current version of kSIgn (>=3.0.0) - because there they are no longer offering a commandline tool. (See [K Softwares tutorial](https://support.ksoftware.net/support/solutions/articles/17170-how-do-i-use-ksign-to-digitally-sign-files-))

The manufacturer of kSign recommends Microsofts own `signtool.exe` that is part of the free [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/). It is a super huge download for just that small tool. It is also part of Visual Studio (probably not a smaller download), you find it's [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) also on the Microsoft homepage. That documentation is huge as signtool.exe is capable of many tasks.

I also found this small guide [how to use signtool.exe with jpackage](https://simplefury.com/posts/java/windows/jpackage-win-codesign/) but it's from Java 15 - so no guarantee that it will work with Java 21.

So while I cannot provide insight what changed from Java 20 to 21, I hope that the signtool replacement will also work for the latest version, or at least give a better error message.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely that certificate used by you is not compatible with Java21 
**Solution:** Please get new certificate from vendor

**Rootcause:** whenever we upgrade to Java version, we need to recreate keystore files because each java version will remove some service providers and add/remove  algorithms/certificates supported

**Reference URLs:**

1. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/21-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8295894 has list of Security Algorithms supported
2. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-F41EE1C9-DD6A-4BAB-8979-EB7654094029  has Security Certificate Provider details
3. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/migrate/removed-tools-and-components.html#GUID-D7936F0D-08A9-411E-AD2F-E14A38DA56A7 has information on  list of Tools removed from Java21 .
4. Please refer Removed Features and Options section on
   https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/21-relnote-issues.html
   [image]

If comodo certificate uses any of these features , Java21 blocks it and signing will not happen.

Comment: kSign is a generic executable signing utility. It has nothing to do with Java.